# create associative data from ffmpeg string result into python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffprobe

To perform video operations I'm using python with the support of ffmpeg. After I've uploaded videos, I need to resize them, so I'll follow these instructions to calculate the video dimensions:

```
link_v = "C:/video/video.mp4"
ffmpeg = "ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=width,height -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 %s"% link_v
info = check_output(ffmpeg, shell=True)
print(info)
```

The console result is something like this:

```
width=350
height=350
```

But I do not care about this, when it is printed as if it were a string, because the real data would be: b'width=350\r\nheight=350\r\n' or ['width=350\r\nheight=350\r\n'].

What I really want to see is an associative data: "{width: 350, height: 350}", once I get then I would call for example width in the info mode ['width'], how can I get this result?

Comment: Will JSON output do?

Comment: @Gyan Yes, a json output would be ideal

Comment: Change `-of` to `json`.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks for the reply. If you want to publish it below, I select it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffprobe offers a JSON writer as an output format. Set `-of` to json

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you need:

`link_v = "D:/video/youtube/video.mp4"`
`ffmpeg = "ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=width,height -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 %s"% link_v`
`info = sp.check_output(ffmpeg, shell=True)`
`dim = str(info).split("b")[1].split('\'')[1].split('\\r\\n')[:2]`
`dim =dict(item.split("=") for item in dim)`
`print(dim)`

and the output would be like this:

{'width': '1920', 'height': '1080'}

Comment: I solved in this way: 1)info = check_output(data, shell=True) 2)jsoninfo = json.loads(info), thanks anyway for the interest